# Form validation index variable issue with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having a strange problem trying to validate 8 radio buttons.  It seems to be with the indexing.  I am looping though 8 radio buttons in order to test if they are checked.  If all 8 buttons are not checked, it will alert the user and `event.preventDefault();`

```
$("#form").submit(function(event) {

        var count = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
            var checked = $("input[type=radio][name=emotion]")[i].checked;
            if (!checked) {
                count = i;
            }
        }
        if (count == 7) {
            alert("You must select at least one emotional state!");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

I've tried reconstrucing the same code in `java` and the condition `count == 7` holds true, but nothing happens in my `jquery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check for checked radio length:

```
$("#form").submit(function (event) {
    if(!$(":radio:checked").length) {
        alert("You must select at least one emotional state!");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I get the alert still when I select one of the eight radio buttons.

Comment: Just an update, I've just tried my webpage using Safari which has been fully reset and its working.  Does this mean there is something wrong with Google Chrome?  As thats the browser its playing up in.  Another thing is that the internet has been awful today and yesterday.

Comment: Works on chrome too. Maybe you didn'd have clear browser cache.